# comparing array of object elements with another object key elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

`const array1= [{row: 101},{row: 102}];`

`const obj1 ={101: 'someValue', 102 : 'someValue1'}`

here I want to return true if array1 of values example(in this case 101 and 102) matches with obj1 key's that are  101 and 102 else need to return false

Comment: And what did you tried so far? You could provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array1.every(({row}) => obj1.hasOwnProperty(row))`

Be aware that if obj1 has another property, e.g. `103: 'someValue3'`, it will still be true.

And also it is [recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#using_hasownproperty_as_a_property_name) to call it using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj1, row)`